# How can I identify a change in a specific column based on the unique identifiers in another column?

Tags: pandas, loops, time-series, sequential

Here's my dataframe:

| date | sec_ID | code |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2015-11-16 | abc | 0 |
| 2015-11-17 | abc | 0 |
| 2015-12-18 | abc | 1 |
| 2016-01-16 | def | 0 |
| 2016-02-16 | def | 0 |
| 2015-11-16 | xyz | 0 |
| 2016-11-17 | xyz | -1 |

The dataframe consists of nearly 4 million rows, for 3000 securities (3000 unique SEC_IDs). This is a time-series based data as we have a code for each day for each security, in a separate column.

What I do want is to iterate through each SEC_ID, and detect the first date when the CODE changed for a particular SEC_ID just retain that row, or the first date for a security if the code is 0 throughout. It is important that the iterator resets for each SEC_ID.

So the desired output would be a dataset comprising of 3000 rows with either 1, 0 or -1 in each case, as shown below:

| date | sec_ID | code |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2015-12-18 | abc | 1 |
| 2016-01-16 | def | 0 |
| 2016-11-17 | xyz | -1 |

I have already sorted the data by security ID and date in ascending order.

So far I have tried doing:

```
data['diff'] = data['code'].diff()
data.dropna(inplace=True) # did this because the first row was understandably a NaN. No other NaNs anywhere in the dataset.
data_first_change = data.loc[data['diff'] != 0]
data_first_change = data_first_change.groupby('sec_ID').nth(0).reset_index()
```

The above doesn't yield the desired output, because the code doesn't reset for each of the sec_IDs.

Any thoughts please?

Comment: Also it seems expected output not matching input sample data, is possible change them?

Comment: I haven't posted any images so can't understand your first comment. I am not clear on your second comment, can you please clarify? Expected output aligns with the input sample data - what exactly is unclear please?

Comment: oops, it looks like pictures, sorry.

Comment: So `def` has a number of dates, starting with `2016-01-16`, then `2016-01-17` and so on. The `code` moves from 0 to 1 on `2016-12-01`, and therefore it is called out in the expected output. Same with `xyz`. Hope this helps clarify.

Comment: yop, so why it is not this rows in input data?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately it is quite big (and confidential :)). I have fixed my post which should hopefully align with your query. Obviously the input dataset is only an example and a snippet of the actual dataset (which is 4 million rows) !

Comment: Maybe help [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Comment: Thanks but do you see my revised post? Is my question still unclear to you?

Comment: It is now super.

Comment: Thanks, look forward to your answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`DataFrameGroupBy.diff`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.diff.html) for difference per groups, replace first missing values and compare for not equal `0`, then get all first rows by [`Series.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.duplicated.html), join together by [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) and remove duplicates by [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html):

```
mask1 = df.groupby('sec_ID')['code'].diff().fillna(0).ne(0)
mask2 = df['sec_ID'].duplicated()
df = pd.concat([df[mask1], df[~mask2]]).drop_duplicates(['sec_ID']).sort_index()
print (df)
         date sec_ID  code
2  2015-12-18    abc     1
3  2016-01-16    def     0
6  2016-11-17    xyz    -1
```

Comment: Worked perfectly, thank you! Can you please explain the use of `ne()` in your code? Thanks!

Comment: It is [`Series.ne`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ne.html), working like `!=`